# Do sub classes inherit the associated classes of super class

Tags: java, inheritance, associations

I just want to clear a concept of inheritance. Do sub classes inherit the associated classes of super class. To make my question clear let suppose an example 
Assume there is a super class Person, having association relationship with BloodGroup class and Address class, and Women and Men as its sub classes, now tell me whether the Sub Classes will inherit these two associated classes from parent class or not?

Comment: write code to communicate it clearly please, general answer: it depends on what access specifier you use

Comment: By associated classes, do you mean classes in the same package?
As Jigar said, what access modifiers are you using?

Comment: I am not coding only making project model right now. Just want to know if this is possible or not?

Comment: It's not about showing actual production code but showing an example that illustrates what you mean exactly. That's still pretty unclear. "associated class" is no exactly defined term.

Comment: in above example, will Women class have BloodGroup class by its parent class?

Comment: classes having Association relationship => associated classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes if they are either `public` or `protected`.

Answer (score 0):

Child classes inherit all but private fields of their parent classes.

Answer (score 0):

A subclass will only inherit the structure (methods and properties) of it's superclass and it's superclass's superclasse's.

If by associated classes you mean import. The subclass does not inherit the super's imports. Imports are file specific and used for compilation of individual .java files.

ie

```
Object
 -Person extends Object
    -Male extends Person
```

Male can use and override the methods and properties of both Person and Object as long as the access modifiers(public/protected/private/package) allow it. Male does not care what objects are used in the methods or what code is run in them, it only uses them based on it's signature(returnType methodName(Parameters)).